# How to log on to a website using my android application?

Tags: android

What can I use to log on to a website using my application? is there a library or something that makes communicating with websites and returning data easy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I use a post request, as you can see in my sources, function login: http://code.google.com/p/tsukiapp/source/browse/trunk/src/net/myfigurecollection/android/webservices/MFCService.java

I have to manage cookies, but it its not mandatory if you just have to validate credentials ;)

Answer (score 1):

Authentificator might be what youre looking for.

Its part of the java.net package and provides a callback method for password authentification.

There is a very basic and easy understanding example how to use it so i´m just going to link it.

Couldnt demonstrate it better!

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/AuthenticatorsetDefaultnewAuthenticator.htm